# Angular ngIf reflect the change to the property

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to change the state of some property on the basis of ngIf?

```
<div *ngIf="(command.form.dirty) ? templateModified = true : templateModified = false">
    CHANGE!
</div>
```

Comment: templateModified is property of div right ?

Comment: @SunilKashyap No, templateModified is variable in my TypeScript behind.

Comment: okay so why don't you change or update templateModified in the component class.

Comment: @Sunil Kashyap - The problem is that I have lists that have controls, within other lists with other controls. Everything is created dynamically, so I try to approach the ngTemplate control. That's the easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using reactiveform you can subscribe to valueChanges of form and change the property.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.command.form.valueChanges.subscribe(
    () => {
     this.templateModified = this.command.form.dirty
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I'm creating dynamic controls. This looks easy, but when you have a dynamic list of controls, that has a second control list with other controls, it's pretty complicated.